# UIView for video list

Tags: objective-c

I am a beginner of objective c, please forgive me if the question is too silly :P

In this stage, I just want to query videos from iphone library and pick the video to get their urls. I have added an UITextField and an UIActivityIndicatorView to the UIView. Now I want to create an area to add the videos. What UI should I use?

Here is my interface for now:

```
@interface videoProcessorViewController : UIViewController
{
    MPMediaQuery *mediaQuery;
    IBOutlet UITextField *feedBackText;
    IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
    IBOutlet _____________? videoLibrary;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `UITableView`, which is the standard iOS control for showing a list of information.  It would probably be easiest to change your controller to a `UITableViewController` and move the `feedBackText` field into a `tableHeaderView`.

Here is a good tutorial to get you started: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/introduction-to-the-ios-uitableviewcontroller